# Sequelize on GraphQL update not return anything

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, graphql, graphql-js

GraphQL return null using Sequelize update.

```
updatePerson: {
  type: Person,
  args: {
    value: {
      type: UpdatePersonInputType
    },
    where: {
      type: WhereUpdatePersonInputType
    }
  },
  resolve(_, args) {
    return Db.models.persons.update( args.value, {
      where: args.where
    });
  }
},
```

Here my request using GraphiQL

```
mutation {
  updatePerson(value: {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", email: "johndoe@example.com"}, where: {id: 1}){
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    email
  }
}
```

and this the result

```
{
  "data": {
    "updatePerson": {
      "id": null,
      "firstName": null,
      "lastName": null,
      "email": null
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe I make mistakes using Sequelize update. Can anyone explain what happens?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41133634/5531595

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, I'm using **MySQL**, **Sequelize** just support **PostgreSQL** if you need return `affectedRows`, but if you use **MySQL** you just can only return `affectedCount`.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcount-affectedrows