# How to return a model back (or anything for that matter) on an update mutation in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I am using the update model method to update an entry in Sequelize using the **mysql2** dialect. It seems as if with MySQL you can only return a count of rows affected. I would like to pass it back as a boolean.

It should be noted that I am fairly new to JS/ES6, Node, pretty much all of this, I am more versed in PHP so I apologize in advance if the answer is obvious or a fundamental misunderstanding of JS, but I promise I have worked on this for hours. The online documentation and online examples for the update method are fairly light.

The closest answer I can find is at: [Sequelize on GraphQL update not return anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093459/sequelize-on-graphql-update-not-return-anything/41133634#41133634)

I have removed irrelevant bits of this code for brevity.

Model:

```js
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Payment = sequelize.define('payment', {
        ...
        processed: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(1).UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: '0'
        },
        ...
    return Payment;
```

Schema:

```js
...
type Payment {
id: Int!
amount: Float!
processedTime: Int
processed: Int!
dueDate: Int!
status: PaymentStatuses

Employee: Employee
Client: Client!
Merchant: Merchant
PaymentType: PaymentType
}

type Query {
getPayment(id: Int!): Payment
}
type Mutation {

updatePaymentStatus(id: Int!, processed: Int!): Boolean

}
```

What I was originally trying to do was:

```js
updatePaymentStatus(id: Int!, processed: Int!): Payment!
```

Resolver:

```js
Mutation {
updatePaymentStatus: async (parent, {id, processed}, {models}) => 
{await models.Payment.update({processed}, {where: {id}})
.then((datareturned) => {return datareturned[0]})}
}
```

If I check my database, the update is actually working correctly. If I console.log(datareturned[0]) I get a 1 (or 0 if no rows were updated).

I would like to be able to return at least a Boolean as described in my schema but no matter what I try, I get null or some other error because the returned value is null. I realize I may be incorrectly assuming returning 1 will be assumed as true but I have also tried:

```
.then((datareturned) => {if (datareturned[0] === 1) {return true}})}
```

In GraphiQL:

```
mutation{
  updatePaymentStatus(id:1, processed:0) 
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "updatePaymentStatus": null
  }
}
```

I am not sure if the problem is with my lack of JS knowledge, or that Sequelize does not return much using the MySQL dialect, or somewhere in between.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i just ran into this last night... i did it like this in my resolver

```
addUserProfileCertification: async (_, args, { models }) => {
      try {
        await models.ProfileCompanyCertification.create(args.input);
        return true;
      } catch (err) {
        logger.error(err);
      }
      return false;
    },
```

and my mutation

```
addUserProfileCertification(input: ProfileCertificationInput!): Boolean
```

GraphiQL result looks like

```
{
  "data": {
    "addUserProfileCertification": true
  }
}
```

You can easily return the whole model if you want though by return a findOne with the id from your args at the bottom of your resolver like...

```
updateUserProfileContact: async (_, args, { models }) => {

      let returnValue = null;
      const { id, input } = args;
      try {
        await models.ProfileContact.update(input, { where: { id } });
        returnValue = await models.ProfileContact.findOne({ where: { id } });
      } catch (err) {
        logger.error(err);
      }
      return returnValue;
    },
```

You just need to tell your mutation to expect a Payment type rather than a Boolean, and you can refine what you want to pass back to the client by selecting only certain fields from payment as part of the mutation that you enter into GraphiQL

Comment: Thank you, the problem was I wasn't using Try Catch but instead using a .then()  I knew it was my noob JS skills. =) I am not very good with promises yet. As far as your answer with returnValue I would get a promise object back not a boolean.

Comment: You must not have used await like I did above that would have given you the promise instead of the Boolean... without that your function would just fire all the way through without grabbing the response from the database

Answer (score 0):

This eventually ended up working for me, changing the Resolver for this to:

```
updatePaymentStatus: async (parent, {id, processed}, {models}) => {
            try {
                const foundPayment = await models.Payment.findByPk(id)
                if (foundPayment){
                models.Payment.update({processed: id}, {where: {id: id}})

                return true;
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                return false;
            }

        },
```

I wanted to be sure the payment id existed before running the update because the update would run regardless if the row existed or not. I'm not sure if I even need the try catch, but I left it in there just in case.

Comment: That might be a good case for findOrCreate but not sure exactly what your business case is, glad you got it going though!!!